# Workflow to Wait until Date Field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can a workflow be told to wait until a specific date, or date field?
It works with timeout equals date, but I would much rather use wait until process time is on or after date.
When I try this the workflow is postponed until our distant ancestors have died of old age; it is the same if I put in a date field instead of a specific date (which is the end goal):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to consider what is considered a "timeout" for the desired behavior.  The following links provide some more context.

Also, unless you have a really specific use case for using a specific date (like year end deadlines or processing) -- you'll probably want to use a datetime field on an entity as the basis for the right side of the comparison.  You can always use the dialog on the right to choose a fixed date/time before or after any of the entity datetime fields.

[image: Detail screen for Timeout wait condition.]

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11291.microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-workflows-wait-and-timeout.aspx

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/11/06/multiple-waiting-workflows-wait-conditions-and-timeouts/

http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2009/07/12/waits-timeouts/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will use the current value of the field each time the workflow is checked.

Related: [CRM2011 Workflow: What happens if the field which is used in the condition of the workflow is updated after the workflow has started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867800/crm2011-workflow-what-happens-if-the-field-which-is-used-in-the-condition-of-th/11870836#11870836)

Comment: That is what I understand should happen, but look at the postpone until: 12/31/9999 1:59 AM That date is not helpful.

Comment: You mean next to `Start Reason`? Does it actually wait till that date? (I would be suprised if it did). That looks like `DateTime.Max` and is probably used to signify a particular workflow state.